# Passing LayoutParams to ViewGroup not working

Tags: android, viewgroup

I have my own layout

```
public class MyLayout extends ViewGroup
```

Inside that Layout I put some buttons. That works fine. But I trie to add LayoutParams

```
ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(80, 80);
Button btn = new Button(getActivity());                 
btn.setLayoutParams(params);    
myLayout.addView(btn);
```

and access it in MyLayout

```
View child = getChildAt(i);
ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = child.getLayoutParams();
```

I only see 0 as height and width. What is wrong in my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try creating your own `LayoutParams` inside your `MyLayout` class.

Something like this:

```
public static class LayoutParams extends ViewGroup.LayoutParams {
    int x;
    int y;

    public LayoutParams(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
      super(context, attrs);
    }

    public LayoutParams(int w, int h) {
      super(w, h);
    }
}
```

Then you will need to override the following methods in the `MyLayout` class:

```
  @Override
  protected boolean checkLayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams p) {
    return p instanceof LayoutParams;
  }

  @Override
  protected LayoutParams generateDefaultLayoutParams() {
    return new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
  }

  @Override
  public LayoutParams generateLayoutParams(AttributeSet attrs) {
    return new LayoutParams(getContext(), attrs);
  }

  @Override
  protected LayoutParams generateLayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams p) {
    return new LayoutParams(p.width, p.height);
  }
```